# Ellipse inscribed in a circle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Please, help me with the following problem:

Starting from the figure below,
[image: ellipse inscribed in a circle]

we know:

$FP=OP-OF=a\cos E-ae$

and from the right triangle $OP_{2}P$, I determined

$P_{2}P = a\sin E$.

I would like to ask you: how can I prove that $P_{1}P/P_{2}P=b/a$ (where a is semi-major axis and b is semi-minor axis of ellipse)?

Can a demonstration be made by means of synthetic geometry or without equation of ellipse?

Comment: Equation of line $PP_1$ is $x = a \cos E \ $. Plug it in the equation of ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$ and find $y$. That is $PP_1$ and it comes to $b \sin E$. Also, $PP_2 = a \sin E$.

Comment: Thank you, @Math Lover, but how can I prove that the equation of line $PP_{1}$ is $x=a\cos E$?

Comment: Can you see why the coordinate of $P$ is $(a \cos E, 0)$?

Comment: So the line parallel to y-axis through $P$ will be $x = a \cos E$.

Comment: So, any point on the line $PP_{1}$ has $x=a\cos E$. Thank you.

Comment: If you want a synthetic proof, please explain what definition of ellipse you want to consider.

Comment: For example, we could draw a circle inscribed in the ellipse, the center $O$ and the radius $b$. Now, we construct the projection of the point $P_{1}$ on the y-axis. Finally we will notice that the circle, $P_{2}O$ and the projection of the point $P_{1}$ intersect in a single point. Unfortunately, I don't know how to show that this is happening. With this aspect, we will obtain some similar triangles, with proportional sides.

Comment: @Augustin Yes, but how do you define an ellipse? By the sum of distances to foci? By the focus-directrix property? Can we take as given, for instance, that $(PO/a)^2+(P_1P/b)^2=1$? You must give some more details.

Comment: Thank you for this remark, @Intelligenti pauca. Considering that, in the other answers, we could see the application of the equation $x^2/ a^2 + y^2 / b^2=1$, I think it would be interesting to have a proof based on the equation proposed by you: $(PO/a)^2+(P_{1}P/b)^2=1$.

Comment: @Augustin Those two equations are the same thing.

Comment: @Intelligenti pauca I understand. So, we can use focus-directrix property.

Comment: If you want a geometrical proof, starting with the focus-directrix definition of ellipse, then you can find it [on page 42 of this book](https://archive.org/details/geometricaltreat00drewuoft/page/42/mode/1up) (it is Cor. 1 of Prop. XIII).

Comment: Thank you, @Intelligenti pauca, but what is the significance of the dot (.) and of the three points arranged triangularly? Also (: :) represents (=), and (:) represents (/)?

Comment: Yes to both your guesses for :: and : The triangle of points means "therefore" and a single dot means multiplication.

Comment: Thank you, @Intelligenti pauca!

Answer (score 1):

Actually that circle is called the **auxiliary circle** of the ellipse and has many nice properties. It can be used to **parameterize** the ellipse $P_1=(a \cos x,b \sin x)$, x being the polar angle of $P_2$ from here it follows the result you asked. And the parameterization follows from **standard equation** of ellipse, i.e., $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$ after plugging in the x coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $P_{1}$(acos(t), bsin(t)), since its on the ellipse,
$P_{2}$(acos(t), bsin(t)) since its on the circle.
P will have co-ordinates (acos(t), 0).

Using distance formula:

$P_{1}P$ = bsint(t),
$P_{2}P$ = asin(t)
Therefore, $\frac{P_{1}P}{P_{2}P}$ = $\frac{b}{a}$.
Here t is just a parametre.

Comment: Thank you, @Ayus Das, but the point $P_{2}$ should not have coordinates $(a\cos t, a\sin t)$? I apologize if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Augustin Yes, that was a typo, I presume.